# Sublime Package Control settings file doesn't list all installed packages

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I installed SublimeText3 on my laptop , installed Package Control, used it to install many other packages ,  headed to the file

```
\%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Package Control.sublime-settings
```

I wanted to backup that file and send it to my Desktop Computer to get the same Packages on my Desktop , however Not all packages where listed in it

Here is how it looks from inside :

```
{
"installed_packages":
[
    "Autoprefixer",
    "CodeFormatter",
    "DocBlockr",
    "SublimeCodeIntel",
    "SublimeLinter",
    "Theme - Flatland",
    "Theme - Sodarized",
    "ToggleQuotes"
]}
```

Many other "already installed" packages are missing , example "Alignment , Emmet ... etc.

Any help why these ones are not there ??

Comment: Did you install those other packages through Package Control?

Comment: Not all of them , for example : I'm sure 100% I've installed "Enhanced Side Bar' from the package control, however it's not listed here ! but when I tried now to remove/reinstall the hidden packages, they appeared in the list ! so I had to repeat this step with them all !

Comment: You don't have to uninstall and reinstall. You can just  add them to the list.  Kinda bothersome but should be a one time thing.  You can use the package control site to make sure you are using the correct names for the plugins.

Comment: Actually I had copied the file names from the installed packages folder and now it works. Thanks :)